# Stochastic differential equations vs stochastic initial conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, initial-value-problems

I'm very new to stochastic calculus and I'm puzzled by what exactly is the difference between solving a stochastic differential equation vs solving a differential equation with stochastic initial conditions.

Most of the information I found online focused on the first kind of problem, i.e. we have a system described by differential equations and a stochastic source, e.g.

$$ \hat L [x(t)] = f(t),$$

where $x(t)$ is a variable of interest, $\hat L$ is some differential operator and $f(t)$ is a random noise term.

On the other hand, often if physics, we are interested in a case where 
a system is described by an ordinary differential equation, but the initial conditions are not known but can be described using a random variable. E.g. we can have

$$\hat L[x(t)] = 0, $$

and where $x_0 = x(t=0)$ is say a Gaussian random variable.

Are these two examples related? Can one system be mapped 
mathematically into another? 
Or are these completely separate type of problems?

Answer (score 0):

A stochastic DE has - in the most simple setup where the filtration is generated by a Brownian motion - a whole Brownian path $ω$ as parameter. That is, $X_t(ω)=X(t,ω)$ where $ω$ is a continuous function and because of this simple setup the Brownian path to the stochastic variable $ω$ is $W_t(ω)=ω(t)$. These then get combined into the symbolism
$$
dX_t(ω)=a(t,ω)dt+b(t,ω)dW_t(ω).
$$
As you see in the infinitesimal increment of the Brownian path, which is almost surely not differentiable, this has no easy translation into an ordinary differential equation. You need the Ito or similar integral and stochastic calculus to ascribe meaning to this symbolism.

Comment: ok, I'm confused a bit. Is this to say, that I can not have a system as described in my first equation above? I would have hoped that for the purpose of this question above we can restrict the discussion were differentiability is not an issue. Are you saying there is no case where this can be done?

Comment: This would be the case if $b=0$ and $a=f(t,X,W)$, so this is also covered. Then the solution does not locally look like a Brownian motion.

Comment: ok, but this doesn't tell me much about the original questions, does it?

Comment: Correction: To deal with the idea behind the first situation, the Ito and Stratanovich calculus was invented. You can not just say "random noise term" without further qualification, and if you really mean something like the derivative of a Brownian motion, then you left the possibilities of classical ODE theory far behind.